# Is it mandatory that I carry my work permit every time I re-enter Canada?

Tags: working-visas, canada

I have an ETA-eligible passport and have recently obtained a work permit. Unlike most other visas it's an A4 document that is quite inconvenient to take with you on trips, since that's one more thing you can lose accidentally.

Is it mandatory that I take this document for re-entry to Canada? What happens if I don't?

Comment: As @dda mentioned, it is a required document, but you don't need to carry it in its perfect form. You can fold it into a passport size and staple it so you don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've asked some colleagues who have had experience with re-entering Canada without the piece of paper and the answer is **no, it's not mandatory**. At the border you will (at worst) be sent to secondary screening where the immigration officer will look up your status. And occasionally they will simply let you in under the ETA without verifying the work status.

**Update:** Tried it myself this week - worked without any issues at the land border. The immigration officer checked the computer to see if my work permit is still valid and then let us through. Didn't even have to go to secondary screening.

**Update #2:** Over the past 10 months I've personally witnessed at least five colleagues who have forgotten their work permit, both driving and taking the bus - no one ever had any issues whatsoever. Not sure why CBSA can't just drop the requirement altogether.

Comment: That's a big **occassionally**. They just might not let you in. I wouldn't trust *some colleagues* over the official website but hey that's me. YMMV.

Comment: @DipenShah see my update

Comment: While this may have worked for you, this is actually ill-advised. Just because a single officer let you in doesn't mean it'll be the same. You are likely to be asked a lot of questions about why you left your papers or subject to secondary screening, which is a big waste of time.

Comment: @UmurKontacı Most of the time it takes them about 30 seconds to look up your visa status in the database. I've talked to about a dozen people who traveled across the border without the work permit and none of them had any serious issues. This is practical first hand information.

Comment: I've done more border crossings than most, and I can say that this is a terrible idea. It's unlikely that you'll be denied entry, but you can be asked more questions or send to secondary screening, which is going to take about 30-45 minutes to clear, at the minimum. Why do want to risk that when you can fold that piece of paper and staple to your passport?

Comment: @UmurKontacı have you ever been personally sent to secondary screening because of a missing work permit? I can't imagine that happening as that information is literally inside the border guards computer. My own personal experience and the experience of a dozen colleagues proves it. I agree that it's easy to keep the paper with you, but my post is mainly for people who have forgotten the work permit and are now worried about going back.

Answer (score 5):

### YES

A work permit is not a visa. It is the legal authorization for you to stay in Canada. However, according to the [Government of Canada](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=1287&top=22), you need **an eTA or a visa, along with your work permit** to enter Canada.

On a side note remember that a visa/eTA can expire while you are in Canada and it's okay as long as you are not planning to leave the country. You will need it only while reentering Canada. You will need a visa/eTA to enter Canada though. However, having a valid work permit is absolutely required for you to legally stay and work in Canada.

Comment: Good answer, but a small clarification: It's even okay for the visa to expire if you plan to leave the country; the important point is that someone in that situation will need a new visa before reentering Canada.

Comment: Good answer. It's a really strange law considering everything is in the government database.

Comment: @JonathanReez You assume that all the databases talk to each other, and do so fluently and regularly... you assume too much.

Comment: @JonathanReez When busy, border personnel may admit you without looking up your information, or only briefly doing so, on occasion, so hard copies of this information can be helpful to them.  Remember that some ports into Canada are tiny little border crossings in the rural prairies, with limited facilities and few personnel.  I used a crossing once (now closed) that averaged three crossings per *day*.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie at such a border crossing, though, you would at least be free from the guilt of delaying everyone else.

Comment: @phoog Sometimes, they're *more* thorough at the quite crossings, actually.  They have more time.  I find that the busier the crossing, the less time I spend in front of the officer, on average.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie I understand.  And on top of that, if there is only one officer, there will be no separate "secondary inspection," at least not without closing primary inspection.  But if the next person isn't expected to arrive for some hours, there won't likely be anyone behind you to delay.

Answer (score 0):

Also, I do not believe that once you’ve shown it to your school or employer, or lastly the bank; don’t carry it. If it gets lost, stolen, or damaged,I think it’s difficult to replace. Carry a copy till you get your provincial ID.